php-pdftk is deleting all data when inserting background or stamp
I am using php-pdftk for filling out a form and i try to insert a stamp (also tried as a background).
Inserting data in fields works perfect. When i insert a stamp, the stamp shows up in resulting PDF - but all fields are emtpy again...
The same happens when using a background.
The Stamp/Background is a valid PDF-File.
Does anyone have a idea or a solution for that problem?
Thank's a lot in forward ;-)
Here's my (very simple) code-snippet:
$pdf = new Pdf($transitionFormTplPath);
$pdf->fillForm($formFieldDataArray)
        ->needAppearances()
        ->stamp($transitionStampPath)
        ->saveAs($transitionFormOutPath);


Thanks a lot! After a lot of tries i did exactly that this afternoon and it worked ;-)
